# bundle idで制限してるGoogle API Keyが全く機能しない

Tags: ios, google-api

### 起きてる問題

iOSアプリのbundle idで制限してるGoogle API Keyが全く機能しない

私は、GoogleのPlace APIを利用したiOSアプリを開発中で、今はTestFlightで実機テスト行う段階まで来ています。
テストに利用するビルドは本番と同じものを利用しており、そうなると利用してるGoogleのAPIにも制限をかけなければなりません。そこで、bundle idを利用した制限設定を行ったのですが、その制限が原因でAPIが全く機能しませんでした。
bundle idの制限を解いたらAPIも機能するので、この制限が動作不全の原因であることは間違い無いはずです。

### 前提

・Expoを使ってビルド及びApp Store Connectへのアップロード行なっている（`eas build`, `eas submit`）
・bundle idが間違ってるという初歩的なミスはありません。（ビルド時にアプリに与えるidもgoogle apiの制限に与えるidも同じでした）

### 具体的にお聞きしたいこと

正しいbundle idでビルドできてるなら普通は、Google API Keyのbundle id制限もパスできるものですか？それともApp Storeにリリースされるまでは、制限をパスできないという仕様があったりするのでしょうか？

起きてる問題の原因またはヒントをご存知の方はご回答をお願いしたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちら、自己解決しました。

App Storeなどは全く関係なく、bundle idで制限したGoogle APIへのリクエスト時は、自分で`x-ios-bundle-identifier`ヘッダーを付与する必要があるようです。

以下が参考になりました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340829/google-map-apis-not-working-after-adding-bundle-identifier-ios